# Returning even and odd numbers in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having a little trouble answering a python quiz that asks:

Given two numbers X and Y, write a function that:
returns even numbers between X and Y, if X is greater than Y else it returns odd numbers between x and y

For instance, take the integers 10 and 2 . the function would return all the even numbers between 2 and 10.

I would really appreciate some help since I'm still a newbie

Here is my code:

```
def number_game(x,y):
  num = range(x,y)
  for e in num:
    if x > y:
      return e%2 == 0
    else:
      return e%3 == 0
```

Here are the test cases:

```
test.assert_equals(number_game(2,12), [3, 5, 7, 9, 11])
test.assert_equals(number_game(0,0), [])
test.assert_equals(number_game(2,12), [3, 5, 7, 9, 11])
test.assert_equals(number_game(200,180), [180, 182, 184, 186, 188, 190, 192, 194, 196, 198])
test.assert_equals(number_game(180,200), [181, 183, 185, 187, 189, 191, 193, 195, 197, 199])
```

Comment: `return e%2 == 0` is a boolean, not a numerical value

Comment: `num = range(x,y)` is this supposed to be non inclusive?

Comment: Your e%3 comparison isn't quite right - you should compare `a%2` in both cases, but to different numbers. Try to figure out yourself to which!

Comment: @vash_the_stampede: based on the testcase, the upperbound is exclusive. Since otherwise `200` should be in the one but last testcase.

Comment: Just use `number_game = lambda x, y: [i for i in filter(lambda i: i%2 == (x > y), range(*(x, y+1) if y > x else (y, x+1)))]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more pythonic way using list comprehensions

```
def number_game(x,y):
    if x > y:
        return [n for n in range(y,x) if n%2==0]
    elif y==x:
        return []
    else:
        return [n for n in range(x,y) if n%2!=0]
```

Comment: Why bother with those `if` clauses in your list comps? You should use the `step` arg of `range`.

Comment: Good point, but since OP used the mod operator, but not quite correctly, i think it's helpful to show it in action. Plus, I think this is better self-documenting code, but that's just my preference

Comment: Fair point. The fact that it's doing more than twice the work it needs to doesn't matter much here. Unless there's a huge difference between x & y. ;)

Comment: `test.assert_equals(number_game(1000000000000000,-100000000000000), [-100000000000000, -99999999999998,...` makes me giggle, tho!

Answer (score 4):

Well there are some problems here:

1. if `x >= y`, then `range(x, y)` is empty, hence the `for` loop will not enumerate any values;
2. `e % 2 == 0` and `e % 3 == 0` are equality checks and hence will return a boolean;
3. `e % 3 == 0` checks if the number is dividable by `3`, not odd; and
4. once you return something, you escape out of the function.

We can however write a function that avoids looping, by first checking the numbers, and then *constructing* the correct `range(..)` object, like:

```
def number_game(x,y):
    if x > y:
        if y % 2 == 1:
          y += 1
        return list(range(y, x, 2))
    else:
        if x % 2 == 0:
            x += 1
        return list(range(x, y, 2))
```

For example:

```
>>> number_game(14, 25)
[15, 17, 19, 21, 23]
>>> number_game(15, 25)
[15, 17, 19, 21, 23]
>>> number_game(25, 14)
[14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24]
>>> number_game(25, 13)
[14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24]
>>> number_game(2,12)
[3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
>>> number_game(0,0)
[]
>>> number_game(2,12)
[3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
>>> number_game(200,180)
[180, 182, 184, 186, 188, 190, 192, 194, 196, 198]
>>> number_game(180,200)
[181, 183, 185, 187, 189, 191, 193, 195, 197, 199]
```

The code can made more compact with:

```
def number_game(x,y):
    if x > y:
        return list(range(y + (y%2), x, 2))
    else:
        return list(range(x+1-(x%2), y, 2))
```

What we thus do is first check if `x > y`, (or not). Since if `x > y` we should construct a a `range(y, x, 2)`, but a problem might be that `y` is odd, so we check if it is odd first, and if so, we increment the value.

A similar thing happens if `x <= y`: we construct a `range(x, y, 2)`, but in case `x` is even, we increment it as well.

Because we make steps of two (the last parameter in the `range(..)`), this will also construct the list more efficiently, since the `range(..)` function will not *test* whether a number is even/odd, but simply increment the varible with `2`.

In case you do *not* wish to "materialize" the iterable (put the elements in a list), but simply return the relevant `range(..)` iterable, we can do this like:

```
def number_game(x,y):
    if x > y:
        return range(y + (y&1), x, 2)
    else:
        return range(x+1-(x&1), y, 2)
```

The advantage of this is that `range(..)` allows fast memberchecks, a range can be sliced very efficiently as well, etc. So you keep the `range(..)` object, and you can *post process* it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the solution using `Generators` (the `yield` keyword)

```
def number_game(x,y):
  num = range(min(x,y),max(x,y))
  for e in num:
    if x > y and e%2 == 0:
      yield e
    elif x < y and e%2 != 0:
      yield e

# you have to materialize generators to lists before comparing them with lists
print(list(number_game(2,12)) == [3, 5, 7, 9, 11])
print(list(number_game(0,0)) == [])
print(list(number_game(2,12)) == [3, 5, 7, 9, 11])
print(list(number_game(200,180)) == [180, 182, 184, 186, 188, 190, 192, 194, 196, 198])
print(list(number_game(180,200)) == [181, 183, 185, 187, 189, 191, 193, 195, 197, 199])
```